# Get the subtraction of two scores from two tables for several usres. Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to access several tables, actually they are the same table but older versions, and get the max of subtracted score from both tables for each manager.

let's say we tables r6 and r10 that have a field called scores.

I need to get the scores from the two tables and subtract the new score (from latest table) form the old one (in an older table) to get the managers score for between period.

let's say table r6 has score = 1 for manager A, and table r10 has score = 5 for manager A. So for manager A the yield score is 5-1 = 4. Which is basically (r10.scores - r6.scores) which will be totalScore.

Now i need to get that totalScore (the score from 10-6) for all managers A-Z and also be able to find the highest one as well.

The question is, how to achieve that in mysql, if not possible, what do u suggest? I am using php btw.

Addition info:

Table's Names:

```
1- ranking_gw6_260912 AS r6
2- ranking_gw10_201012 AS r10
```

Used Fields:

```
1- rx.manager_id
2- rx.scores
```

These fields exist in both tables.

n.b gw refers to game weeks of football matches, The website is for fantasy football and I am trying to get the winner of the contest who has the highest score from game week 6 to game week 10. Sadly, the database only stores the latest score overriding the on for the previous week. so I cannot get each week score and thus I am left with the overall score. Yet, we have a backup tables for each week that I will be using to get the between score.

Comment: can i single manager_id has multiple scores on the table? eg `1, 12`,`1, 3`,...?

Comment: No, each manager has only one record in ranking table. Say  manager_id = 1234, that manager will exist only once. Thus if you select scores from ranking where manager_id= 1234; you will get only one result e.g 320.

Comment: so on the list of manager having the difference of their score, you also need to rank them? so the result will also be one if it has no duplicate highest diff?

Comment: yes I need to rank them.  e.g mng1 sub score=4. mng2 sub score=6. mng3 sub score=6. it's unlikely for two managers to have the same sub score. But if that happens, I will need both unless it would be unfair for the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since fields exists on both tables, use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  r6.manager_ID, (r6.scores - r10.scores) totalScore
FROM    Table1 AS r6
        INNER JOIN  Table2 AS r10 
            ON r6.manager_ID = r10.manager_ID
WHERE   (r6.scores - r10.scores) = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(totalScore)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT  (r6.scores - r10.scores) totalScore
                FROM    Table1 AS r6
                        INNER JOIN  Table2 AS r10 
                            ON r6.manager_ID = r10.manager_ID
            ) cc
        );
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo** *(two queries included)*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a038f/4)
- [**SQL Fiddle Demo** *(with tie score)*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be0da/1)

or

```
SELECT  r6.manager_ID, (r6.scores - r10.scores) totalScoreByHighest
FROM    Table1 AS r6
        INNER JOIN  Table2 AS r10 
            ON r6.manager_ID = r10.manager_ID
ORDER BY totalScoreByHighest DESC
```

Comment: hmmm, wonderful, guess I am lucky today to have you around. It works as charm.  Chosen as correct answer. 
+1 for the attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
SELECT r10.scores - r6.scores 
    FROM ranking_gw10_201012 AS r10 
    JOIN ranking_gw6_260912 AS r6 ON r6.manager_id = r10.manager_id
ORDER BY r10.scores - r6.scores
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in php, or whatever language you are using.

Retrieve the score for each table, when you receive your data loop through and subtract and keep a track of the highest value as your run through.  It will be plenty fast enough unless you have millions of managers.

Comment: Test the speed, I think you might find its quick enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though if it's possible to make it in sql (which is quite simply based on the above answers) there will be no need to add any php complexity to the code. 
So far not sure how the simple query up there works. Feels dump now for posting such question. hahahha.